# change WebView asset location by java

Tags: java, webview, permissions, location, offlineapps

I make 100% offline app by WebView. In this app a html file who show me the location path of own. Now the problem is that when open app it's show "file///assets/" like this but it not a correct path .
I want that it show like "storage/emulated/0/"
How can I do?

I nothing try because I busy in making game logic so please help how to change or create a shortcut who show location "storage/emulated/0/"